# Why my reputation Reduced by -1

Tags: discussion, voting

I downvoted the Answer on this question [Webform send multiple email](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/webform-send-multiple-email). As you can see that is spam. In case Answer is removed by the time you read this question, I have taken screen shot as below,

> I have deleted the screenshot of that answer which was here, **as unknowingly, it is creating a permanent replica of that spam**. It was not my intention, but to point out to answerer and to provide the evidence, as first I thought to give the link to answer, but spam questions gets deleted within minutes, hence there would have no evidence, hence I did take a screen-shot. Anybody who still wants to see it anyhow, go check [this revision](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/208535/1) (remember: it's spam ...).

My Account Summary

> [image: Downvote for this question on my]

Did I do something wrong? If I was not supposed to downvote, What I should have done for this answer?

**UPDATE-1:** It did credited again. Probably after the answer was removed.

[image]

Comment: I doubt it is your intend, but by adding that screenshot here again, you have created a permanent replica of that spam message. User **LOAN** must like that, also because the eMail to be used is still included twice ... Are you sure you still want that image to be included in your question? If so, how about "hiding" anything that is not relevant to what your question is about?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, indeed it should be not there, I have removed and updated that place with reason. Thanks

Comment: Much better ... check if you like my minor extra update (if not just rollback ...).

Comment: Much much better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [down-vote an answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), your reputation is reduced by 1; that is how down-voting an answer works. In the past, also down-voting a question would cause you to lose 1 point, but that has been changed.

When you see a spam post, [just flag it as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam/192831#192831); the system automatically down-vote it. Plus, when the post is flagged as spam from 6 users, it is automatically deleted. A moderator will just need to destroy the spammer account.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks you...